# What Windows Phones support long exposure photography?

Tags: camera

Does any Windows Phone support exposures that are:

1. 15 seconds or longer, ideally going to up to a few minutes. But 15 seconds is the minimum I need.
2. Real long exposures, not faked by combining several shorter ones.
3. The ISO should automatically decrease as the exposure increases, to ensure correct exposure. In other words, the photo should not end up too dark or too bright because I chose a particular exposure duration. Ideally, I should be able to do night photography (landscapes, etc) at base ISO.
4. The photos need to be at full resolution, not 1 or 2 megapixels. If the camera supports a >8 megapixel resolution, I'm fine with 8 megapixel long exposures.
5. I'm fine with needing to install a third-party camera app.

Does any Windows Phone support such long exposures?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum exposure time a Windows Phone can do is currently 4 seconds. I'd recommend a Lumia Phone with PureView camera, like the Lumia 930, 1020 or 1520 for best results.

Apart from that you can take multiple images and blend them / find an app that does that for you. However, you'll then won't have continuous exposure.

Comment: It's not true that every phone should be able to do that. I was told that the Lumia 1020 supports a maximum exposure duration of only 2.something seconds. And my iPhone 5s supports only 0.5 seconds.

Comment: You're right, the phones all have a restriced exposure time. For all the phones mentioned above, it's 4 seconds. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAb4WsklYK4
So I guess the only way to go here would be to take multiple 4 seconds exposure pics and blend them together. I know, thats not the solution you were looking for. I updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The Lumia 1020 supports up to 4 seconds at ISO 100 with the Nokia Camera app, which isn't going to be quite long enough for what you're after.

In general, [smaller sensors are less suited for long exposures](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/50201/21), so you may be wanting to push further than currently technology allows.

Comment: My old point and shoot could take 15 second exposures, and it has a 1/2.5-inch sensor, which is not much bigger than the 1/3-inch and similar sensors we see in many phones. BTW, the question you linked to talks about the night sky. I'm talking about photos that have a far more light in it, like a landscape with streetlights.